# Get rid of unused value warning from assertion

Tags: c++, clang, assert

I wanted to create a meaningful assert like so:

```
assert(("precondition failed", false));
```

And it workd fine under *GCC*, but *Clang* warns me about unused value, the value `"precondition failed"`.

Do you guys know some way to disable this warning in code (no command-line arguments or non-portable code, please)? Rewrite the assert is a fine answer too.

Comment: What's the point of `"precondition failed"` in there? Isn't it reduced to a comment?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you call a function, but some properties of input value must be respected. most of the times the asserts are meaningful like assert(num >= 0), but sometimes there is a complicated flow-control and if any is hit, then there is a assert(false), not helpful for a error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways, which generate no warnings even with `-Wall -Wextra pedantic`:

```
assert(((void)"precondition failed", false));  // #1
assert("precondition failed" && false);        // #2
```

Comment: i believe some static analyzers can warn about solution `#2`, but i like solution `#1`, it's like most of unused variable MACROS are implemented and it's unlikely it'll become a warning in the future. =)